# PHP/MYSQL - Check whether it have duplicated record before inserting new record

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose I have a table called "device" as below:

```
device_id(field)
123asf15fas
456g4fd45ww
7861fassd45
```

I would like to use the code below to insert new record:

```
...
$q = "INSERT INTO $database.$table `device_id` VALUES $device_id";
$result = mysql_query($q);
...
```

I don't want to insert a record that is already exist in the DB table, so how can I check whether it have duplicated record before inserting new record?

Should I revise the MYSQL statement or PHP code?

Thanks

UPDATE

```
<?php
    // YOUR MYSQL DATABASE CONNECTION
    $hostname = 'localhost';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';

    $database = 'device';
    $table = 'device_id';
    $db_link = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
    mysql_select_db( $database ) or die('ConnectToMySQL: Could not select database: ' . $database );
    //$result = ini_set ( 'mysql.connect_timeout' , '60' );

    $device_id = $_GET["device_id"];
    $q = "REPLACE INTO $database.$table (`device_id`) VALUES ($device_id)";
    $result = mysql_query($q);
    if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I understood well your question you have two ways to go, it depends how you would like to do the task.

**First way** -> A simple query can returns a boolean result in the `device_id` (Exists or not) from your database table. If yes then do not `INSERT` or `REPLACE` (if you wish).

**Second Way** -> You can edit the structure of your table and certify that the field `device_id` is a `UNIQUE` field.

**[EDITED]**

**Explaining the First Way**

Query your table as follow:

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` WHERE `device_id`='123asf15fas'
```

then if you got results, then you have already that data stored in your table, then the results is 1 otherwise it is 0

In raw php it looks like:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `your_table` WHERE `device_id`='123asf15fas'");
if (!$result)
{
   // your code INSERT
   $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $database.$table `device_id` VALUES $device_id");
}
```

**Explaining the Second Way**

If your table is not yet populated you can create an index for your table, for example go to your SQL command line or DBMS and do the follow command to your table:

```
ALTER TABLE `your_table` ADD UNIQUE (`device_id`)
```

*Warning: If it is already populated and there are some equal data on that field, then the index will not be created.*

With the index, when someone try to insert the same ID, will get with an error message, something like this:

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Comment: Could you explain more for second way? Thanks.

Comment: @Charles Yeah for sure, take a look at my answer one more time, I had edited it..

Comment: It works, so the second way is the easiest way to achieve the requirement. Could you also explain more on First way for my learning? Thanks

Comment: @Charles It is great that works! For sure I will explain also the first way. I will edit the answer again.

Comment: Note that you may want to use `INSERT IGNORE` to make it clear to anyone reading your code that you know a record with the key may already exist.

Comment: @Michael You're right, if I use INSERT IGNORE the statement will not generate errors, instead will generate warnings. Is a good way also.

Comment: Found that `if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)`, if yes insert, if no don't insert, is also useful for this case.

Comment: @Charles Yeah! There are many ways if you dig deep enough.. :)

Comment: Concerning the first case, testing `!$result` doesn't work. 
As @Charles say, you have to use:
`if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)`

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to use as few SQL queries as possible. You can try:

```
REPLACE INTO $database.$table SET device_id = $device_id;
```

[*Source*](http://www.kavoir.com/2009/05/mysql-insert-if-doesnt-exist-otherwise-update-the-existing-row.html)

Comment: Seem not work for "REPLACE" statement, it still inserting new record if it have duplicated record, please check my update.